# Cannot get correct count

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to total the unique package id's in the following query, but when I run this it will show me just 1 for each row regardless if the package id occurs more than once.  Is there something I am not doing correctly?

```
select 
trans.package_id, 
trans.destination, 
trans.date_time, 
count(trans.package_id) as count 
from
    (select 
    pl.package_id, 
    pl.destination, 
    to_char(pl.tran_date,'MM/DD/YY-HH:MI:SS') as date_time 
    from package_log pl
    where pl.destination in 
    ('MRAUD-08','MRAUD-09','MRAUD-10','MRAUD-11','MRAUD-12','MRAUD-13','MRAUD-14','MRAUD-15','MRAUD-16') 
    union all
    select 
    pl.package_id, 
    pl.destination, 
    to_char(pl.tran_date,'MM/DD/YY-HH:MI:SS') as date_time 
    from package_log pl
    where pl.destination 
    in ('MROC-01','MROC-01','MROC-02','MROC-03','MROC-03','MROC-04','MROC-05','MROC-06','MROC-07','MROC-08','MROC-09','MROC-10','MROC-11','MROC-12','MROC-13','MROC-14','MROC-15','MROC-16','MROC-17','MROC-18','MROC-19','MROC-20')
    and pl.source in
    ('MRAUD-08','MRAUD-09','MRAUD-10','MRAUD-11','MRAUD-12','MRAUD-13','MRAUD-14','MRAUD-15','MRAUD-16')
    union all
    select 
    pl.package_id, 
    pl.destination, 
    to_char(pl.tran_date,'MM/DD/YY-HH:MI:SS') as date_time 
    from package_log pl
    where pl.source
    in ('MROC-01','MROC-01','MROC-02','MROC-03','MROC-03','MROC-04','MROC-05','MROC-06','MROC-07','MROC-08','MROC-09','MROC-10','MROC-11','MROC-12','MROC-13','MROC-14','MROC-15','MROC-16','MROC-17','MROC-18','MROC-19','MROC-20')
    ) trans
group by 
trans.package_id, trans.destination, trans.date_time
order by 
trans.package_id, trans.date_time;
```

I need it look like:

```
11325   MRAC-10 07/12/17-08:20:44   1
11403   MRE-18-1 07/12/17-06:55:45  1
11404   MRC-17  07/11/17-06:40:08   1
11407   MRC-18  07/12/17-07:04:33   1
11411   MRD-18  07/13/17-06:21:22   2
11411   MRD-18  07/15/17-05:34:28   2
```

Comment: My guess is that it's showing only one because you're grouping on the date and time as well - you probably don't have multiple packages delivered at the same second.

Comment: is there a way i can grab the total packages regardless of the time it was scanned?

Comment: Yes - but you need to be specific - do you want the total of 'X' delivered forever? or within a certain timeframe?

Comment: Also FYI, you don't need a `UNION` in your query above - you can use conditions (`AND` and `OR`) instead.

Comment: I updated the original post to show how I want it to look.  I cant use AND/OR because I want the to see how long it takes to transfer from one destination to another using that destination as a source.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not able to follow your requirements at all. What's the difference between what your data looks like and how you would like it to look?

Comment: The last two rows will just show the count as 1 for each row in my query, the way i want it to look should show 2 because the package_id occurs twice.

Comment: please show us the result of your sub-query that you called "trans"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want a *Windowed Aggregate*:

```
select 
   trans.package_id, 
   trans.destination, 
   trans.date_time, 
   count(trans.package_id) 
   over (partition by trans.package_id, trans.destination) as count 
   -- maybe
   -- over (partition by trans.package_id) as count
from
    (select 
...
    ) trans
-- no Group By
order by 
   trans.package_id, trans.date_time;
```

Comment: perfect man, thanks.  anyway i can limit query by a certain count number?

Comment: You need to add another nesting level to add a WHERE-condition on count.